# How do I create a column which automatically resolves tickets in phabricator?

Tags: phabricator

I am trying to create a column in phabricator which automatically resolves tickets (i.e. 'Released' column). I know I can manually batch update tickets to resolve them but I would like to know if this is possible automatically. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that with column, you mean a column on a projects workboard? In that case, no, it's not currently possible to change the state of a task by moving it to another column. However, it's a feature that's requested and that's being worked on, see [Support workboard column triggers which activate when a task is dropped into a column](https://secure.phabricator.com/T5474)